# post files from postman to PHP

Tags: php, json, api, postman, form-data

I'm trying to send some data from postman to server but PHP always return null, PHP only gets the data when I send it using raw body.

[image: postman form-data]

PHP Code:

```
<?php

  require_once("_config.php");

  if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == AUTH_USER && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == AUTH_PW){

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    echo $data;
  }

?>
```

Comment: If you're sending the request as `form-data`, which you are, then use `$_POST` instead of `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

Comment: @waterloomatt I tried that and it didn't work but actually $_FILES worked instead. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys, I solved it by removing one of postman headers. I removed Content-Type.

[image: postman Content-Type header]